# Python - Playing infinite video with audio openCV, stuck at audio

Tags: python, opencv

I'm stuck at audio..
Is there any easy way to put that two together? 
Do I have to sync them both or can I somehow just extract audio to the existing code? :/
I'm new in python  :P

My code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


file_name = "path to video"
window_name = "window"
interframe_wait_ms = 30

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file_name)
if not cap.isOpened():
    exit()

cv2.namedWindow(window_name, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty(window_name, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

while (True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        cv2.imshow(window_name, frame)
    else:
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)

    if cv2.waitKey(interframe_wait_ms) & 0x7F == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The `cv2.imshow` is pretty limited in functionalities and should be used only for debugging purposes. I don't think it supports audio output.

Comment: Yeah, but there is a way 100%, not with openCV, but something with ffmpeg and openCV, just i dont know how

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i resolved this using ffpyplayer, but i still have problems when video reloads, music is bugged